# Return each array item incrementally with each function call when passed as callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an array of objects like:
`[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}];`
I also have a function that is recursive and accepts a function as a parameter:

```
function recursiveFunction(getResponse) {
   const result = getResponse();
   
   const conditionMet = check(result);

   if(conditionMet) {
      return result;
   }

   return recursiveFunction(getResponse);
}
```

How can I create a function `getResponse` so each time that it is called in `recursiveFunction` it will return the next iteration of my array?

For example upon each recursion it should be getting the next object in the array:

```
function getResponse(index) {
   return array[index ++];
}
```

And when I call it:

```
const firstIndex = -1; // Because index ++ in function
const result = recursiveFunction(getResponse(firstIndex));
```

I understand why it is only returning the first value but I'm not sure how I can modify it to return the next index in the array when calling it again.

Comment: `getResponse()` should be a closure in an environment containing the current array index and array. It can increment the index and return that array element.

Comment: This seems like a homework assignment, so don't ask for the code.

Comment: I guess I should've provided context. The `recursiveFunction` in my case is a function that recursively calls an api endpoint and then finally returns when a condition is met (essentially polling same endpoint).
I am trying to write a unit test for that particular function and my array is a mock of responses hence why I'm using a callback so I can pass in the function to make a `GET` request and also pass in another function which just returns the responses in my mock.

Comment: OK, it's not homework. But we still expect you to make an attempt to solve it first, then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: In ES6 you can just create a function in a block containing `let` variables for the array and index. In ES5, use an IIFE to create an environment for the variables.

Comment: I didn't really want to add my attempt to solve it at first because it's actually pretty bad and I've been stuck on this for a while now but have added it in my edit

Comment: Wouldn't subsequent calls reset the variables for array and index though? I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: The variable initialization should be outside the closure function, so calling the function doesn't reset anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this in JavaScript would be to use the built-in [Iteration Protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) -

```js
const myinput =
  [ {a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}, {d:4} ]
  
const it =
  myinput.values()
  
console.log(it.next())
console.log(it.next())
console.log(it.next())
console.log(it.next())
console.log(it.next())
```

```js
{value: {a:1}, done: false}
{value: {b:2}, done: false}
{value: {c:3}, done: false}
{value: {d:4}, done: false}
{value: undefined, done: true}
```

You could make your own `iter` function which returns a function like the one you describe -

```js
  
function iter(iterable) {
  const it = iterable.values()
  return () => it.next().value
}

const inputA = [1,2,3]
const inputB = ["a","b","c"]

const nextA = iter(inputA)
const nextB = iter(inputB)

console.log(nextA()) // 1
console.log(nextA()) // 2
console.log(nextB()) // "a"
console.log(nextB()) // "b'
console.log(nextA()) // 3
console.log(nextB()) // "c"
console.log(nextA()) // undefined
console.log(nextB()) // undefined
```

In your program, you will have to check for `undefined` to know when there are no values left -

```js
function recursiveCheck(check, getResponse) {
  const result = getResponse()
  if (result === undefined)
    return "not found"
  else if (check(result))
    return "condition met"
  else
    return recursiveCheck(check, getResponse)
}

const output = recursiveCheck(myChcek, iter([{...}, {...}, ...]))

console.log(output)
```

Using recursion in this particular cases means you the size of your input will be limited. If you simply use `for..of` all of your problems go away -

```js
function iterativeCheck(check, iterable) {
  for (const result of iterable)
    if (check(result))
      return "condition met"
  return "not found"
}

const output = iterativeCheck(myCheck, [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...])

console.log(output)
```

See also [Symbol.asyncIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) for how this approach can be used on async iterables.

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the function as the argument, not calling the function.

```
const result = recursiveFunction(getResponse);
```

Also, if you initialize the index as `-1`, you need to use `++index`, not `index++`.